# How to ensure Excel prospect list data remains current on ZoomInfo, including job titles, emails, and phones?

Tags: excel, validation, time, contacts, info

I am manually cross-referencing each entry in an Excel prospect list with records on ZoomInfo to verify current job titles, emails, and phone numbers. This process is time-consuming and inefficient. I'm seeking a more streamlined solution to ensure the data's accuracy without checking each record individually.

I attempted to manually update each record by comparing Excel data with ZoomInfo profiles. I expected this method to confirm data accuracy but it proved to be excessively time-consuming. The actual outcome is an updated list, but the process is not sustainable due to the large volume of entries and the rapid pace of data changes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.